# How to retrieve descriptive message from Spring response.sendError(...) on user side?

Tags: java, spring, jquery, exception

I have an exception handler defined as following in a Spring controller:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Customized4ExceptionHandler.class)
public void handleCustomized4Exception(
    Customized4ExceptionHandler ex,
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.sendError(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED.value(),
        "zzzzzzz");

}
```

When the error is triggered, I get the following on the user side:

[image]

The error code is correct, but the "zzzzzzz" descriptive message is not displayed. How can I display it on the user side?

My Javascript is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:  prefix + "/throwCustomized4ExceptionHandler",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function(result) {
        alert('Unexpected success !!!');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status + " "
                   + textStatus + " "
               + errorThrown + " !");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as following:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Customized4ExceptionHandler.class)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) 
@ResponseBody
public String handleCustomized4Exception(
    Customized4ExceptionHandler ex) {

    // return "zzzzzzz"
    return ex.getSpecialMsg();

}
```

and

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:  prefix + "/throwCustomized4ExceptionHandler",

    async: true,
    success: function(result) {
        alert('Unexpected success !!!');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(jqXHR.status + " " + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be available as `jqXHR.statusText`.